# npm install --g gulp - hangs

Tags: npm, gulp

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> npm install --g gulp
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Karol\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\np
m-cli.js" "install" "--g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.12.162:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

I have a trouble with npm install. I can't install gulp and other libraries. Installation hangs and then i got the error. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution :-)

```
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
```