# NPM Install is giving Error: connect ETIMEDOUT (Without proxy)

Tags: visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2017

I just created a new .Net Core 2.0 Angualar project template and get a strange error on restoring the packages.

Part of the output:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/extend/-/extend-3.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.0.162:443
```

Later part of the output:

```
23980 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Web\\External\\Node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Web\\External\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
23981 error node v5.4.1
23982 error npm  v3.3.4
23983 error code ETIMEDOUT
23984 error errno ETIMEDOUT
23985 error syscall connect
23986 error network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.0.162:443
23986 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
23986 error network and is related to network connectivity.
23986 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
23986 error network
23986 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
23986 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
23987 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Most solutions I found was about setting up the proxy. I have no proxy.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38614783/2441442):

```
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
```

Which does nothing change.

I also resetted my network adapter and pc. Also I tried `ipconfig -flushdns`.

`tracert` is also working fine:

```
Routenverfolgung zu a.sni.fastly.net [151.101.0.162]
über maximal 30 Hops:

  1     4 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    28 ms    28 ms    28 ms  loopback0.80.rdsl.99.nue.de.net.telefonica.de [62.52.195.28]
  3    34 ms    29 ms    27 ms  bundle-ether3.0001.dbrx.01.nue.de.net.telefonica.de [62.53.3.154]
  4     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  5    34 ms    36 ms    32 ms  ae14-0.0001.corx.01.fra.de.net.telefonica.de [62.53.22.86]
  6    32 ms    32 ms    32 ms  bundle-ether15.0002.dbrx.02.fra.de.net.telefonica.de [62.53.26.0]
  7    31 ms    38 ms    36 ms  ae6-0.0001.prrx.11.fra.de.net.telefonica.de [62.53.19.146]
  8    31 ms    30 ms    31 ms  fastly2.fra.ecix.net [62.69.146.89]
  9    33 ms    31 ms    35 ms  151.101.0.162

Ablaufverfolgung beendet.
```

If I call `https://registry.npmjs.org/extend/-/extend-3.0.1.tgz` in browser, I get the package offered for download.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what is happening...

But as a workaround, I have installed the [Node MSI](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and [configured visual studio](http://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-update-nodejs-andor-npm-latest-version/) to use this one instead.

Tools > Options > Projects & Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools

[image: GUI]

Now it is working. But I feel wrong using this workaround. If anybody has some pointers, how to fix the root of the problem, I would be more than happy.

Comment: For current version of VS2017 (15.6.1), the path is: `Tools > Options > Projects & Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools`

Comment: Also couldn't find what went wrong as this is a fresh install, anyway, using the workaround and moving on...

Comment: Duplicate? Does [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515#28818172](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515#28818172) solve your issue?